# Problem displaying hyphen in webview?

Tags: android, webview

i  am trying to display html in webview but problem is it is showing euro sign instead of **'**

when i look at html by debugging it shows everything fine but not in webview.
any one guide me what is the solution to this problem?

my code

[image]

```
_webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        _webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

            _webView.loadData(_urlfromSummarie, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For those who still need a simple answer, you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9402988/3739412

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a declaration in the document itself, for example:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
...
```

Also, [LoadDataWithUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is generally better than loadData, it doesn't require URLEncoder.encode (slow), and doesn't keep a long data url in the webview's history memory.

Comment: thanks alot. this is what i was looking for i just added html head and meta tags and document inside body tag and now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your UTF-8 text is being rendered as plain ASCII--  does "UTF-8" in the encoding parameter need to be lowercase?  It's lowercase in the API documentation.