# Encoding issue with WebView's loadData

Tags: android, encoding, webview

I'm loading some data, containing latin-1 characters, in a WebView using

```
String uri = Uri.encode(html);
webview.loadData(uri, "text/html", "ISO-8859-1");
```

When displayed, the latin1 characters are replaced by weird characters.

If I load the html directly in a TextView (just to test), latin characters are properly displayed.

Anybody can help?

Thanks

**html:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <!-- some html -->

</html>
```

Comment: Your device can support the fonts?

Comment: @xDragonZ I'm not sure what you mean, but it's a galaxy s and I can see latin characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android. WebView and loadData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/android-webview-and-loaddata)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Only way to have it working, as commented [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1733#c23):

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", html, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

No URI encoding, utf-8... loadData bug?

Comment: I think this thread proposes a more elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412763/string-encoding-problem-in-webview

Comment: I'm not being able to show the inverted exclamation point (¡, &#161;, &iexcl;) using any of these methods. Does anyone know how to work this around?

Answer (score 52):

```
myWebView.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

This works flawlessly, especially on Android 4.0, which apparently ignores character encoding **inside** HTML.

Tested on 2.3 and 4.0.3.

In fact, I have no idea about what other values besides "base64" does the last parameter take. Some Google examples put null in there.

You should always use UTF-8 encoding. Every other character encoding has become obsolete for many years already.

Comment: This is an interesting hack... but works for me on Android 4.3! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, a great hack indeed. Tested OK on Android 4.4.2.

Comment: String is in Unicode format in Java, how do i encode it with utf-8?

Comment: @Shawn: Unicode is standard, UTF-8 is one of the encodings for Unicode. Android uses UTF-8 internally. You should be fine without any changes.

Comment: I'm sorry - can you show me how to encode a java String to UTF-8? it is UCS-2 internally. Note I'm saying String, not a byte stream; Any way, I guess it's irrelevant. It just tell the browser the encoding of this data scheme is not US-ASCII

Answer (score 14):

```
String start = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset='UTF-8' /></head><body>";
String end = "</body></html>";

webcontent.loadData(start+ YOURCONTENT + end, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

One of solution of problem.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. Decodes \u chars (like \u016b etc.)

Comment: Awesome! that worked as expected.
BTW I didn't use null as the last parameter:
webcontent.loadData(start+ YOURCONTENT + end, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "UTF-8");

Answer (score 8):

I have display © 2011 and it was displaying Â©.

With the below code i have achieved displaying correct value © 2011

```
webViewContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that:
Firstly, loadData() method is used to load raw html code. 
Secondly, just put the html code directly to the loadData(), don't encode it

You might wanna try like this:

```
webview.loadData(uri, "text/html", "ISO-8859-1");
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the problem of getting a weird character like Â here and there. Tried different options, but the one that worked is below.

```
String style_sheet_url = "http://something.com/assets/css/layout.css";
    String head = "<head> <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />" + 
            "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" + style_sheet_url + "\" /></head>";    
    String locdata = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" + head + "<body>"+ data + "</body></html>";
    wv_news_text.loadData(locdata, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

wv_news_text is the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

> **Info from Java docs about loadData method**
>
> Loads the given data into this WebView using a 'data' scheme URL.
>
> Note that JavaScript's same origin policy means that script running in
>   a page loaded using this method will be unable to access content
>   loaded using any scheme other than 'data', including 'http(s)'. To
>   avoid this restriction, use loadDataWithBaseURL() with an appropriate
>   base URL.
>
> The encoding parameter specifies whether the data is base64 or URL
>   encoded. If the data is base64 encoded, the value of the encoding
>   parameter must be 'base64'. For all other values of the parameter,
>   including null, it is assumed that the data uses ASCII encoding for
>   octets inside the range of safe URL characters and use the standard
>   %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range. For example,
>   '#', '%', '\', '?' should be replaced by %23, %25, %27, %3f
>   respectively.
>
> The 'data' scheme URL formed by this method uses the default US-ASCII
>   charset. If you need need to set a different charset, you should form
>   a 'data' scheme URL which explicitly specifies a charset parameter in
>   the mediatype portion of the URL and call loadUrl(String) instead.
>   Note that the charset obtained from the mediatype portion of a data
>   URL always overrides that specified in the HTML or XML document
>   itself.

Following code worked for me.

```
String base64EncodedString = null;
                        try {
                            base64EncodedString = android.util.Base64.encodeToString((preString+mailContent.getBody()+postString).getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(base64EncodedString != null)
                        {
                            wvMailContent.loadData(base64EncodedString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");  
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wvMailContent.loadData(preString+mailContent.getBody()+postString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```