# Display local content on a WebView starting at a given anchor

Tags: android, html, webview, anchor

I'm displaying an HTML document using a `WebView`. The HTML document is contained in an HTML string. I pass the HTML string to the `WebView` by using its `loadDataWithBaseURL()` method, as follows (I got it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627448/2586922)):

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://not/needed", getResources().getString(R.string.htmlString), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Now, I'd like to show the HTML document contained in that HTML string starting not at the document's beginning, but at a given *HTML anchor* contained in the HTML string.

Can I do that with `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL()`? Or more gnerally: is there any method to show local content on a WebView starting at an anchor?

Comment: I don't know if it works with that WebView method but as a workaround you could inject some JavaScript that gets executed when the page is loaded and that sets the location to "#YourAnchor".

Comment: @NobuGames Thanks! Actually, I don't know JavaScript, and anyway I would prefer a cleaner solution if it exists...